# vit or vat command not working correctly (sublime text 3 vintageous plugin)

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

when I enable the plugin "vintageous" on sublime text3, "vit" or "vat" command not working correctly with html codes.
this happens when the wrapper element has <img> which doesn't have end tag (like </img>).

```
I need to select all class="sub" element.

<div class="super">
     <div class="sub">text</div>
     <div class="sub">text</div>
     <div class="sub"><img src="url" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

what can I do for that? any suggestion will be appreciated.

I'm using:
Mac OS 10.11.6
Sublime text 3

Comment: Why not just try `vi>` or `va>` instead...

Comment: It means  focusing inside &lt; and &gt; right?  this time I need to select whole html elements exist inside of the wrapper element.i believe that "vit" means v(visual) + i(inside) + t(tag).